# Typescript: How to use key type as enum in an object keeping all enum values as optional?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, enums

I am using a enum type as key for an object:

```
enum Level {
  Novice, Intermediate, Pro
}

type Players = { [key in Level] : string[]}
```

Upon trying to create an object of type players with just Novice and Pro, I get the error saying Intermediate is not present:

```
const mapping: Players = {
  [Level.Novice]: ["Neo"],
  [Level.Pro]: ["John Wick"]
}
```

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out that this can be done by marking the key as optional in the type

```
type Players = { [key in Level]? : string[]}
```

Please notice the '?' which lies outside the `[]`

I thought it was a good learning so I shared by answering my own question.